# Odoo - Sales Order - Tranfer is not generating accouting entries

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I have a problem: After doing a transfer(screenshot: click on Apply) there is no accounting entries generated (in Journal entry) despite the configuration made for auto-generate accounting entries and configuring product category as well:

Settings -> Warehouse -> Accounting

Product categories-> Account properties

Question: where is the function that triggers the generation of accounting lines? or any other suggestions

10x
[image: screenshot - Transfer]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my configuration of the transfer (stock.move object), when the source location is a type view => no accounting entries are generated, otherwise if the source location type is "internal location" then the accounting entries are created successfully.

How to see the source location type of the transfer:

Sales orders->go to your order->click on "view delivery order"-> under "Stock Moves" -> click on a specific line

Locations -> Source Location -> Location Type:

source location type "View" --> won't generate accounting entries

source location type "Internal Location" --> generate normally accounting entries